# How to get a model by modelname in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have model LandingSnippet that contains attribute `...model = CharField()...`, and it is related to context keyword (for example `cars` in `context` below)

I have next code in my view

```
def GeneratedLanding(request):
    snippets = LandingSnippet.objects.all().filter(view_on=True).order_by('order')

    context = {
        'snippets':snippets,
        ...
        'cars':Car.objects.all(), # this is cars
        ...
    return render(request,'qlanding/generateindex.html',{'context':context})
```

how i can get `querySet cars` that is in context by keyword `cars` as a string

for example

```
{{context}}
```

prints

```
{'snippets': <QuerySet [<LandingSnippet: Snippet1Title>, <LandingSnippet: 2 - about - Лучшая служба развозки детей>]>, 'services': <QuerySet []>, 'cars': <QuerySet []>, 'faqs': <QuerySet []>}
```

and

```
{{snippet.model}}
```

prints

```
cars
```

QUESTION:
How can i get the `{{ context.cars }}` ? I think something like `context[snippet.model]` where snippet.model='cars'

i want push it inside another template when include

```
{% if snippet.module %}
  {% with "qlanding/snippets/module/"|add:snippet.module|add:".html" as path %}
  {% include path with model=context[snippet.model] %} # But this is incorect while rendering
  {% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can I see your model?

Comment: return render(request,'qlanding/generateindex.html',context)

Comment: @MohammadAli here is file with my model https://dropmefiles.com/l1dFv

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simple template tag like this:

first in your app directory create a directory named `templatetags` this directory must contains an empty file named `__init__.py`

create a file with any name in this directory. for example `load_from_context`

write these code on this file

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.tag(name="GetFromContext")
def get_from_context(parser, token):
    bits = token.split_contents()
    node_list = parser.parse(('endGetFromContext',))
    variable = bits[1]
    return GetFromContextNode(node_list, variable)


class GetFromContextNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, node_list, variable):
        self.node_list = node_list
        self.variable = variable

    def render(self, context):
        variable_value = template.Variable(self.variable).resolve(context)
        with context.push():
            context['model'] = context.get(variable_value)
            return self.node_list.render(context)
```

then in your template you can use it like this

```
{% load load_from_context %}

{# any code in your template #}

{% GetFromContext snippet.model %}
    {% include path %}
{% endGetFromContext %}
```

Comment: Hi, i got error

'load_from_context' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
fontawesome
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tinymce_tags
tz

Comment: I've just redone all steps, with switched off server

Comment: changed first line: `from django import template`

Actuall problem is endGetFromContext is not registered.

Comment: you right. Its a typing error. change line `node_list = parser.parse('endGetFromContext')` to `node_list = parser.parse(('endGetFromContext'),)`. Im update answer

Comment: Hi, I found from documentation about brackets and tried already. but i got error `Invalid block tag on line 24: 'endGetFromContext', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? `

Comment: are you sure write code correctly? please double check the code

Comment: check this `parser.parse(('endGetFromContext',))`.

Comment: i got the same error still. but after you shared your knowledge i found another short solution. i read documentation carefully. 
      
`      from django import template
      register = template.Library()
      @register.simple_tag
      def get_model_from_context(context,model_name):
          return context[model_name]
`

`
     {% get_model_from_context context=context model_name=snippet.model as model %}
      {% include "qlanding/snippets/module/"|add:snippet.module|add:".html" with model=model %}
`
I've made your solution shorted

Answer (score 0):

@vorujack , I get the same error still. but based on your solution I got next.

```
  from Django import template
  register = template.Library()
  @register.simple_tag
  def get_model_from_context(context,model_name):
      return context[model_name]
```

and how I used in view

```
 {% get_model_from_context context=context model_name=snippet.model as model %}
 {% include "qlanding/snippets/module/"|add:snippet.module|add:".html" with model=model %}
```

many thanks for @vorujack